# Using toCharArray to check if String has any non-digits

Tags: java

So I'm new to java and trying to write some code for a project. I'm trying to use toCharArray to check if String has any non-digits. This is my code I've written so far:

```
public void setMobile(String mobile) 
{
   boolean ok = true;
   char[] mob = mobile.toCharArray();
   for(int index = 0; Character.isDigit(mob) == true; index++)
   {

   }

   if(ok == true)
   {
       this.mobile = mobile;
   }
}
```

I'm trying to check if mobile has any letter, and if so, do not assign mobile to this.mobile.

Comment: In your for loop, do you want `Character.isDigit(mob[index])`?

Comment: If you don't mind not using .toCharArray() and you have Java 8+, you can use the following one-liner:
`boolean ok = mobile.codePoints().allMatch(Character::isDigit);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`String#matches(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches-java.lang.String-) where the parameter is a *regular expression*, [`\D` matches any non-digit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html). Like,

```
public void setMobile(String mobile) {
    if (!mobile.matches("\\D")) {
        this.mobile = mobile;
    }
}
```

If you really want to do it with `toCharArray()` you might use a `for-each` loop and short circuit return on a non-digit. Like

```
public void setMobile(String mobile) {
    for (char ch : mobile.toCharArray()) {
        if (!Character.isDigit(ch)) {
            return;
        }
    }
    this.mobile = mobile;
}
```

**Or**, using a `Pattern` and `Matcher`; and only setting `mobile` if all the characters are digits. Like,

```
public void setMobile(String mobile) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(mobile);
    if (m.matches()) {
        this.mobile = mobile;
    }
}
```

Comment: OMG, thank you so much. I know sounds dumb but I spent 6 hours reading and trying to figure out this question you've answered in within seconds. If you have time could you answer a few questions about the code? So the ch is of type char? Also, is the code checking every single number or letter in the character array?

Comment: @kirra The [`for-each` loop documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html), you can read it as "for each char ch in the char[] returned by mobile.toCharArray()". It stops if any character isn't a digit, otherwise yes.

Answer (score 4):

I assume you want to learn the solution in basic java.
My suggestion would be check each character if it is a number or not something like this:

```
public void setMobile(String mobile) 
{
    boolean flag=true;
    for(int index=0;i<mobile.length();index++)
    {
        if(mobile.charAt(index) < '0' || mobile.charAt(index) > '9')
            flag=false;
    }
    if(flag==true)
        this.mobile=mobile;
}
```

Much simpler and intuitive and no need for extra data structures.

Comment: `Character.isDigit` is pretty intuitive compared to using the two comparisons.

Comment: I agree but for someone who is just learning java they might not know such a function (I didnt to be honest) exists where as they can just compare if a certain characters lies between the given range.

Answer (score 0):

while some of the answers given before me are correct, I feel they only give you the answer to the problem without explaining what was your error.

Notice that one of the problems your code has is that you never set the `ok`variable to false, therefore you will always enter inside the if statement.

Another error is that you are assuming the only characters in a String are digit or letters, therefore checking for `Character.isDigit()` will tell you if that is or isn't a digit, but if the character is a backslash for example, `Character.isDigit('\')` will return false, even though it is not a letter.

the proper way to check if something is a letter or not is to check if it is between 'a' and 'z', or between 'A' and 'Z'.

once you have understood what is wrong, I would advise trying to change your current code to work before continuing with the answers given, just so you can understand how to do it in the simplest way and than continue with the answers given.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **regular expressions**. `\\d` matches digits from 0 to 9 and `+` means that there must be at least 1 digit.

```
public void setMobile(String mobile) {
    this.mobile = (mobile.matches("\\d+")) ? mobile : this.mobile;
}
```

The code above uses ternary operator, but this also works:

```
public void setMobile(String mobile) {
    if (mobile.matches("\\d+"))
        this.mobile = mobile;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers, in Java 8 there is a `chars()` method on interface `CharSequence` (which `String`) implements) which returns an `IntStream` of the codepoints of the characters in the string. You can use the `allMatch` method on the stream with a predicate to ensure that all the codepoints are digits as follows:

```
public void setMobile(String mobile) {
    boolean ok = mobile.chars().allMatch(Character::isDigit);

    if (ok) {
        this.mobile = mobile;
    }
}
```

At this point the `ok` variable isn't really pulling its weight, and we could simply substitute the expression into the condition of the `if` statement. Or, if you want to get a little crazy (although this is arguably entering code-golf territory), you could rewrite it as a one-liner with a ternary operator:

```
public void setMobile(String mob) {
    mobile = mob.chars().allMatch(Character::isDigit)? mob : mobile;
}
```